# FileNotFound Error in python when running .py file from visual basic

Tags: python, vb.net, file-not-found

I was trying to make a assistant which can perform simple task like shutting down the computer etc. For this i chose python and visual basic..... visual basic for displaying(frontend applicaton) and python for performing tasks(backend application). So i create a py file named main.py and created a folder named query and in it created a file named query.jarvis which can simply be opened as a text file. The vb(visual basic) program just write text into query.jarvis and then run the main.py file. When I run it manually by double clicking the main.py file it works fine(like in query was "shutdown" and after running main.py file by double clicking my computer shutdown) but when I try to run it from vb it shows the error file not found query\query.jarvis . I even tried to convert py file to exe by pyinstaller but it again showed the same error but only when I run it from vb.

***main.py()**

```py
def check(q):

    #here was performing task according to query

f=open("query\query.jarvis") 

    #here the error occured

x=f.readlines()

d=x[0]

d=d.strip()

q=d.lower()

check(q)*
```

***vb.net**

```vb
objWriter123.Close()

Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(moddir + "query\query.jarvis")

   
      #here moddir is the directory of main.py file

objWriter.Write(UserQuery.Text)

objWriter.Close()

UserQuery.Text = ""

Process.Start(moddir + "main.py", AppWinStyle.MinimizedNoFocus)*
```

Comment: As for your issue, the problem is likely the fact that you're not wetting the `WorkingDirectory` for the new process. Many applications assume that the current directory is whatever folder they were run from while your code will set it to the same current directory as your app. Whatever folder you would "cd" to in a console window is probably what you should set as the `WorkingDirectory`.

Comment: Argh! Please read what I actually wrote and not what you think I wrote. What happens when you double-click a file in File Explorer is irrelevant. I didn't say that you were using the wrong file path for *main.py*. I specifically said that you weren't setting the `WorkingDirectory` when you were running it. Try opening a search engine and finding out how to set the `WorkingDirectory` when calling `Process.Start`.

Comment: Ohkkk I have figured it out now...A big heartful thanks to you...The problem was in main.py file...Thanks to you again although u have been kinda rude but ok

Comment: I don't like to waste my time repeating myself. I think it's kinda rude to ask for help and then not properly read advice when it's provided. Also, if you have answered your own question before anyone else does, you should actually post an answer showing the solution, to help others that may find this question with the same or similar issue. That's how this site works. To the best of my knowledge, you don't need a minimum reputation to do that, but I have no way to check for sure.

Comment: sir, actually we (me and my friend with same stackoverflow id) are school students only, and we are trying something new...we encountered this issue and once we are done with what we are doing, we will for sure post the solution for others and help the community grow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

process.start sometimes has weird outcomes. i usually manage to fix it by adding explorer.exe into the mix.

```
Process.Start("explorer.exe", moddir & "\main.py")
```

also note this extra backslash, that you might have missed. in \main.py

**note**

in vb you concat strings with the & symbol instead of the + symbol.